# Problema no Result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou com problemas tanto para apresentar a mensagem de erro como para inserir as informações no BD 
 modulo - express-validator

1 - Erro apresentado na gravação das informações:

Result { formatter: [Function: formatter], errors: [] }

2 - Não mostra a mensagem de erro referente a validação no navegador somente no console.

```js
// admin.js


const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
module.exports = (app) => {
 
  app.get('/formulario_inclusao_noticia', (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin/form_add_noticia',{validacao:{},noticia:{}});
  });
 
  app.post('/noticias/salvar', [
 
    check('titulo','Título é obrigatório').not().isEmpty(),
    check('resumo','Resumo é obrigatório').not().isEmpty(),
    check('resumo','Resumo tem que ter entre 10 a 100 caracteres').isLength({ min: 10, max: 100 }),
    check('autor','Autor tem que ter entre 10 a 100 caracteres').isLength({ min: 10, max: 100 }),
    check('autor','Autor é obrigatório').not().isEmpty(),
    check('data_noticia','Data é obrigatório').not().isEmpty(),
    check('noticia','Data é obrigatório').isEmpty()
  ], (req, res) => {
    let noticia = req.body
 
    const errors = validationResult(req);
 
    console.log(errors);
 
    if(errors){
      res.render('admin/form_add_noticia', {validacao: errors, noticia: noticia});
      return
    }
    console.log(validacao);
    let conn = app.config.dbConnection();
    let noticiasModel = new app.app.models.NoticiasDAO(conn)
 
    noticiasModel.salvarNoticia(noticia, (error, result) => {
      res.redirect('/noticias')
    })
  })
}
```

```html
//form_add_noticia.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title>Formulário de cadastro de Notícia</title>
  </head>
 <body>

  <h1>Adicionar notícia</h1>
  <br />
  <% if (validacao) { %>
   <ul>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < validacao.length; i++) { %>
     <li>
      <%= validacao[i].msg %>
      <% console.log(validacao[i].msg) %>
     </li>
    <% } %> 
   </ul>
  <% } %>  

  <form action="/noticias/salvar" method="post">
   <label>Título</label>
   <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" value="noticia" placeholder="Título da Notícia" />
   <br />
   <label>Resumo</label>
   <input type="text" id="resumo" name="resumo" placeholder="Resumo da Notícia" />
   <br />
   <label>Nome autor</label>
   <input type="text" id="autor" name="autor" placeholder="Autor da Notícia" />
   <br />
   <label>Data dos Fatos</label>
   <input type="date" id="data_noticia" name="data_noticia" placeholder="Data da Notícia" />
   <br />
   <label>Notícia</label>
   <textarea id="noticia" name="noticias" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual a versão do `express-validator`?

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mais como vejo a versão do express-validator? @Sorack

Comment: No `package.json` da sua aplicação você pode conferir as bibliotecas de dependência e suas respectivas versões

Comment: @Sorack obrigado pela explicação, segue a versão "version": "6.1.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente você não está seguindo o exemplo disponível na documentação do [`express-validator`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/). Nela você pode conferir que o seu `if` de verificação dos erros deve ser da seguinte forma:

```
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.render('admin/form_add_noticia', { validacao: errors.array(), noticia: noticia });
}
```